# solidity - transfer money without specifying the amount

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, transfer

I have a list of products, each product has a price.

I would like to create a function that can be called by a user and automatically checks whether the user's balance has enough money to buy the product, it transfers a fee from the buyer to the contract's balance and the price from the buyer to the seller.

Is that possible?

This code obviously cannot work, because the smart contract has to be fed, somehow.

```
    struct Product {
        uint id_prod;
        address owner_addr;
        uint curr_price;
        bool onSale;
    }

    struct Owner {
        uint id_owner;
        address payable addr;
    }

    // function to receive ethers into the contract
    receive() external payable {
    }

    // function to send ether
    function pay(address payable _to, uint amount) private {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: amount}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    function buyProduct(uint _id_product) external payable productOnSale(_id_product) buyerHasEnoughMoney(_id_product) alreadyOwner(_id_product){

        Owner storage _owner = getOwnerStruct(_id_product);
        Product storage _product = ProductList[_id_product];
        
        // pay 1 finney to the contract
        pay(payable(address(this)), 10**15);
        pay(_owner.addr, _product.curr_price);


        _product.owner_addr = msg.sender;
    }
```

I think the workaround is to create a payable function where the buyer can specify the amount of money so that the smart contract receives the money, and subsequently, it transfers the price amount to the seller.

My question is if there exists a way to avoid the buyer specifying the amount and just calls a function that directly takes money from their balance, holds a fee to its own balance, and transfers the price amount to the seller.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the function `payable` you send value when you call the function. Looks like you have an ecommerce website, selling some products. So when you call the contract function on frontend:

```
await contract.methods.buyProduct(
    // id should be in hex format
    hexId,
  ).send({from: account, value:valueOfItem})
```

You call this function when you submit the form. it will pop up the metamask, metamask will calculate gas cost and if you have enough balance it will submit the request otherwise metamask will return you error